# Change Wallpaper according to time

Tags: windows, batch, windows-registry, vbscript

I need to open it on startup to change the wallpaper at day n night

```
Dim objShell
str1 = "C:\Users\AnB\Desktop\Texts\Projects\Project WallTime\Day.bat"
str2 = "C:\Users\AnB\Desktop\Texts\Projects\Project WallTime\Night.bat"
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
if hour(time) < 17 then
objShell.Run str1
if hour(time) > 16 then
objShell.Run str2
end if 
end if
```

**This is the vbs that will open batch files that will change the Reg**

**Batch file for day**

```
@echo off
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\AnB\Desktop\Texts\Projects\Project WallTime\Day and Night\Day.png" /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

**Batch file for night**

```
    @echo off
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\AnB\Desktop\Texts\Projects\Project WallTime\Day and Night\Night.png" /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

***but when i use the vbs it did not change the registry***

**Please Help**

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just create a task in windows to start each batch at a specific time?

Comment: @FatalBulletHit ,I want to change it this way, Day=00 to 16 and Night=15 to 23

Comment: So you create a task at 00:00 and 16:00 which starts the corresponding batch. And if you want to check and change it at system start you create a batch which checks the time and starts the corresponding batch file as well. I don't know how Windows handles tasks when it's in stand-by or sleep, but other than that, tasks should work just fine. :)

Comment: @FatalBulletHit , then it'll change only at 00.00 and 16.00 right ?,I want to change when I turn my PC on ,not just at 00.00 and 16.00

Comment: "And if you want to check and change it at system start you create a batch which checks the time and starts the corresponding batch file as well." Maybe I should add: put it in Autostart or use Windows task scheduler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it ,thanks for the help

```
@Echo Off

Set "locn=%UserProfile%\Desktop\Texts\Projects\Project WallTime\Day and Night"
Set "rstr=Reg Add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V Wallpaper /D "
Set "str1=%locn%\Day.png"
Set "str2=%locn%\Night.png"
Set /A "now=10%TIME:~,2%" 2>Nul

If %now:~-2% Lss 17 (%rstr% "%str1%" /F >Nul
) Else %rstr% "%str2%" /F >Nul
RunDll32 User32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters >Nul
```